# Ember.js belongsTo not loaded in component first time

Tags: ember.js, controller, ember-data, relationship, belongs-to

Brief description of the project: 
I have developed my own express API that is linked to EMBER with ember-cli-auth. I have some problems with displaying a BelongsTo relation. I want to display a farm with a linked company.

Problem: 
I receive the data from the API but not the relations data the first time. When I go the second time the relationdata is in ember-data and it works perfectly. What do I do wrong?

Farms belongsTo a company.

What my api send: 
http://localhost:3000/v1/farms/552bc6f7becd0d3691588267

```
{
  "farm": {
    "_id": "552bc6f7becd0d3691588267",
    "name": "UpdatedFarm2",
    "owner": "552bc6f6becd0d3691588262",
    "company": "552b90c39debd4d44512da5b",
    "complex": "552bc6f7becd0d3691588266",
    "continentCode": "EU",
    "countryCode": "FR",
    "city": "Dendermonde",
    "province": "Oost-vlaanderen",
    "housenumber": 10,
    "zipcode": 9200,
    "street": "beurzestraat",
    "__v": 0,
    "updatedAt": "2015-04-13T13:39:03.117Z",
    "createdAt": "2015-04-13T13:39:03.096Z",
    "nofHouses": 0,
    "flocks": [],
    "contacts": []
  }
}
```

**Model Farm**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Farm = DS.Model.extend({

  city: DS.attr('string'),
  contacts: DS.hasMany('contact',{async:true}),
  company: DS.belongsTo('company',{async:true}),
  complex: DS.belongsTo('complex',{async:true}),
  continentCode: DS.attr('string'),
  countryCode: DS.attr('string'),
  flocks: DS.hasMany('flocks',{async:true}),
  housenumber: DS.attr('number'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  nofHouses: DS.attr('number'),
  owner: DS.belongsTo('user',{async:true}),
  province: DS.attr('string'),
  street: DS.attr('string'),
  reference: DS.attr('string'),
  lastReportAt: DS.attr('date'),
  zipcode: DS.attr('number'),
  createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
  updatedAt: DS.attr('date')

});

export default Farm;
```

**Model Company**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Company = DS.Model.extend({

  name: DS.attr('string'),
  owner: DS.belongsTo('user',{async:true}),
  complexes: DS.hasMany('complex',{async:true}),
  farms: DS.hasMany('farm',{async:true}),
  flocks: DS.hasMany('flock',{async:true}),
  createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
  updatedAt: DS.attr('date')

});

export default Company;
```

**Routes/farms/farm**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-    route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin,{
model: function(param){
  return this.store.find('farm', param.id).then(function(farm){
    console.log("farm in modelhook" , farm.get('company').content);
    return farm;
  });
},

afterModel: function(model) {
  console.log("farm in aftermodelhook",model.get('company'));
  return model.get('company');
},

setupController: function(controller, model) {
  console.log("farm in setupcontroller",model.get('company'));
  controller.set('model', model);
}

});
```

**Controller farm**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend(
{
  actions: {
    edit: function() {

      console.log(this.get('model').get('company'));

    }
  }
}
);
```

**Templates/farms/farm**

```
{{#if model}}
  <div class="title-underline">
    <h1> Contact info </h1>
    <div class="actions-block">
      <a {{ action 'edit' }} class="btn-edit"> edit </a>
      <a {{ action 'delete' }} class="btn-delete"> delete </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="farm-info-main">

    {{farm-info-farm model=model}}

  </div>

{{/if}}
```

**Templates/components/farm-info-farm.hbs**

```
<div class="block-item farm-info-farm">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Company : {{model.company.name}}
    </li>
    <li>
      Complex: {{model.complex.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Conclusion**

When I console.log the hooks in the route (model, aftermodel,setupcontroller) I get the right data in my log. But when I check the ember data the first time. The content is null in the belongsTo attribute. Second time I receive an object in the content of company from a farm.

What to do?

Comment: You should be able to delete the setupController in your routes/farm/farm. It duplicates/overrides what your model hook does, and could be messing things up.

Comment: okay, thank you, but still not receive the proper model in my controller. You  know what the problem is? @R3tep

Comment: after removing ```afterModel``` and ```setupController``` did you get null farm or null company? @CollinVdv

Comment: @Sushant the company is null the first time when I go to farm and the give the object through the route. When I go directly through the url, it company is always null